# Sphinx autosummary cannot find module

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I am trying to generate documentation for https://github.com/deepchecks/deepchecks. However, I have lots of errors. The error I am concerned about is below:

```
[autosummary] failed to import deepchecks.vision.Context.
Possible hints:
* ImportError: no module named deepchecks.vision
* ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'torch.ops.torchvision._cuda_version'
* AttributeError: module 'deepchecks' has no attribute 'vision'
```

Can someone point me to fix the error or point in right direction?

Comment: Look in `conf.py` and set the path to your package so that Sphinx can import it.

Answer (score 0):

The way I ended up resolving this issue was by importing the modules in `conf.py`

```py
import deepchecks
from deepchecks import vision
```

Adding the path did not work because `vision` modules is in extra requires of setup.